# In SQLIte, how to add a check on an existing column

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite, I cannot find the syntax to add a check on an existing column. Is there a direct method to do that? Thanks.

Comment: For example, I have a table. The table has a integer column _id. There is no check before. But now I want to add a check on _id. Is there a straightforward way to add a check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [not possible](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html); you have to recreate the table.